# Confused on notation Rudin Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is stated as follows

Represent $\ell^1$ as the space of all real functions $x$ on $S= \{(m,n): m\geq 1, n \geq 1\}$, such that
$$
\|x\|_1 = \sum |x(m,n)| < \infty. 
$$
Let $c_0$ be the space of all real functions $\gamma$ on $S$ such that $y(m,n) \rightarrow 0$ as $m+n \rightarrow \infty$, with norm $\|y\|_\infty = \sup |y(m,n)|$.

Let M be the subspace of $\ell^1$ consisting of all $x \in \ell^1$ that satisfy the equations
$$
mx(m,1) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty x(m,n)      \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (m = 1, 2, 3, \ldots)
$$

(a) Prove that $\ell^1 = (c_0)^*$.

(b) Prove that $M$ is a norm-closed subspace of $\ell^1$.

(c) Prove that $M$ is weak*-dense in $\ell^1$ [relative to the weak*-topology given by (a)].

(d) Let $B$ be the norm-closed unit ball in $\ell^1$. In spite of (c), prove the weak*-closure of $M \cap B$ contains no ball. Suggestion: If $\delta > 0$ and $m > 2/ \delta$, then 
$$
|x(m,1)| \leq \frac{\|x\|}{m} < \frac{\delta}{2}
$$
if $x \in M \cap B$, although $x(m,1) = \delta$ for some $x \in \delta B$. Thus $\delta B$ is not in the weak*-closure of $M \cap B$. Extend this to balls with other centers.

I'm struggling with what a Schauder basis would look like for $C_0$ as stated.

Would it be equivalent to say $x(m,n) = \{x_n^{(1)}, x_n^{(2)}, \ldots, x_n^{(m)}\}$ in other words a sequence of sequences.

Is the subspace $M$ the collection of sequences shifted right one?

To show this is norm closed is it sufficient to say that 
$$
\left |\sum_{n=2}^\infty x(m,n) \right |  \leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty |x(m,n)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(m,n)|< \infty.
$$

and last, for weak* dense is it correct to say for $\gamma \in C_0$, $x_n \in M$, and $x \in \ell^1$ 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup | \gamma x_n| \rightarrow 0
$$
since $\gamma \rightarrow 0$, and $x_n$ is bounded. 
Similarly for $x$. Which would imply weak* dense.